# How do I transform array output sorted in lexicographic order to numeric order

Tags: text-processing, sort

I have a text file that consists of data in this form:

```
int array[0]
int array[1001]
int array[1002]
int array[1003]
int array[2]
int array[2001]
int array[2002]
...
```

In other words, the numbers appear to be listed in some sort of lexicographic ordering. I want to sort the file so its contents are as follows:

```
int array[0]
int array[1]
int array[2]
int array[3]
int array[4]
int array[5]
int array[6]
...
```

How would I perform this sorting transform? `sort` does not appear to be sufficient for the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `sort` it numerically on the `[` delimiter:

```
sort -t\[ -nk2,2 <<\IN
int array[0]
int array[1001]
int array[1002]
int array[1003]
int array[2]
int array[2001]
int array[2002]
IN
```

#### OUTPUT

```
int array[0]
int array[2]
int array[1001]
int array[1002]
int array[1003]
int array[2001]
int array[2002]
```

Answer (score 1):

For situations where you have text and numbers, an alternative is the `--version-sort`

```
sort -V
```